# Edge getattribute() not working, returning null

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am trying to create an extension for edge and I currently facing an issue with the `getAttribute()` function. It's not returning me the attributes of the element that I am looking for.

This is how my code looks like on Edge with out come:
`document.head.getAttribute("data-xd-id") ;` *Outcome: `null`*

This is how my code looks like on Chrome with out come:
`document.head.getAttribute("data-xd-id") ;` *Outcome: `AAggv0A`*

Chrome browser correctly returns the expected outcome/id but edge returns `null`. After further investigation it seems that Edge is denying access to return these elements/id? Why is that the case? Is there any work around to this?

---

Head Details:

You can either go to http://www.msn.com/en-ca and see the head markup or its here:

```
<head data-info="lots of stuff here" ... data-xd-id="AAggv0A" data-delayed-js="...
```

Comment: We need to see the `head` markup (and probably the context around it). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem that we can copy and paste to see it happen for ourselves.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder please see the head details above or go to msn.com/en-ca and look at the head in the source.

Comment: When you were asking/editing your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: You appear to have missed out reading the "minimal" part of that page above. :-)

Comment: Thanks... Will keep that in mind for next time :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to retrieve the `data-` attributes from a `HTMLElement`, you should consider using the `dataset` property.

**Using your example**:

- `document.head.dataset` to get all `data-` attributes inside an `Object` from the `<head>` tag.
- `document.head.dataset["xd-id"]` to get the `data-xd-id` value from the `<head>` tag.

More information at Mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset